# Haskell binary datatype of specific bitwidth

Tags: haskell, types, binary

I would like to create a datatype representing a binary number of specific bit width.

So a type `bin3` --> `0bXXX`, `bin7` --> `0bXXXXXXX`

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried to install packages such as `bv-sized` but they will not build correctly. I do not need much functionality so I thought I could implement my own.

The error I got when trying to install `bv-sized` was

```
$ cabal install bv-sized
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0...
Building parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0...
Failed to install parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0
Build log ( /home/.../.cabal/logs/ghc-8.2.2/parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0-4VdYssETRDcLceu2pgYcjQ.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-99266/parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0'
Configuring parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0...
Preprocessing library for parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0..
Building library for parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0..
[ 1 of 32] Compiling Data.Parameterized.Compose ( src/Data/Parameterized/Compose.hs, dist/build/Data/Parameterized/Compose.o )

src/Data/Parameterized/Compose.hs:30:45: error:
    Type variable ‘k’ used in a kind.
    Did you mean to use TypeInType?
    the type signature for ‘testEqualityComposeBare’
   |
30 | testEqualityComposeBare :: forall k l (f :: k -> *) (g :: l -> k) x y.
   |                                             ^

src/Data/Parameterized/Compose.hs:30:59: error:
    Type variable ‘l’ used in a kind.
    Did you mean to use TypeInType?
    the type signature for ‘testEqualityComposeBare’
   |
30 | testEqualityComposeBare :: forall k l (f :: k -> *) (g :: l -> k) x y.
   |                                                           ^

src/Data/Parameterized/Compose.hs:30:64: error:
    Type variable ‘k’ used in a kind.
    Did you mean to use TypeInType?
    the type signature for ‘testEqualityComposeBare’
   |
30 | testEqualityComposeBare :: forall k l (f :: k -> *) (g :: l -> k) x y.
   |                                                                ^
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-99266/parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
bv-sized-1.0.3-Ip13iwUWQ7u421I8e2amlq depends on bv-sized-1.0.3 which failed
to install.
parameterized-utils-2.1.2.0-4VdYssETRDcLceu2pgYcjQ failed during the building
phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

GHC 8.2.2

Comment: Do you need it to be space-efficient? If not, the [`Vec n Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Vector-Fixed-Boxed.html#t:Vec) would do.

Comment: But you should better ask how to fix the problem with `bv-sized`, because that's certainly the right tool for the job.

Comment: Is there an upperbound to the number of bits, for example if always smaller than 64, we can use a `Word64` to *encode* it and thus create a data type that presents it as a 3 bit.

Comment: Yes I would like to use bv-sized but I am getting confused with cabal, every time I install a package there is a problem with some dependency (im new to this)

`Vec n Bool` might be a good way to go. I bodged it by using `Int` and a smart constructor - would this be the same as what you mean with `Word64`?

Comment: @confusedandsad: is it possible to [edit] the question with the error trace that cabal prints?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Add also your compiler version.

Comment: Have done that now

Comment: Uh, 8.2.2 is very old (2017). You should upgrade if you want to do such type-level computation stuff. It's super easy with [GHCup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/). Alternatively you can try `cabal install --constraint 'parameterized-utils<2'`, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: BTW you should actually never `cabal install somelibrarypackage`. Instead, generate a `yourproject.cabal` file (using `cabal init`) and specify `bv-sized` under its `build-depends`. Then you just run `cabal build` and it does any necessary installations automatically.

Comment: Ah it was just the version available on the RHEL repos which is why I ended up using it. 

Thanks I will try that with Cabal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are at most 64 bits, we can easily encode that on a 64-bit word. This would mean that we can work with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Word(Word64)
import GHC.TypeNats (KnownNat, natVal)
import Numeric.Natural (Natural)
import Text.Printf (printf)

newtype Bin (n :: Natural) = Bin Word64 deriving (Eq, Ord, Read)

_sz :: KnownNat n => Bin n -> Int
_sz = fromIntegral . natVal

instance KnownNat n => Show (Bin n) where
  showsPrec d g@(Bin v) = showParen (d > 0) (("0b" ++ printf ("%0" ++ (show (_sz g)) ++ "b") v) ++)
```

The `_sz` thus works with a `Bin n` and returns the `n` value as `Int`, regardless what the `Bin n` object is, this can even be undefined. And we then thus use that to show that number of bits, for example:

```
ghci> Bin 3 :: Bin 3
0b011
ghci> Bin 3 :: Bin 5
0b00011
```

of course this is just a minimal example. For example it has no *smart constructor*. But we can complete this, with for example constructors, and extra instances to `Num`, `Bits`, etc.

Comment: I'd add some explicit [`n < 64`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Ord.html#t:-60-) constraints.

Comment: You could use `Integer` in essentially the same way and relax the "at most 64 bits" constraint -- at a small efficiency cost, of course. (And this is exactly what `bv-sized` does.)

Answer (score 0):

Might be an overkill for your purposes, but [SBV](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv) supports arbitrary sized bit-vectors, both signed and unsigned:

```hs
Prelude Data.SBV> :set -XDataKinds
Prelude Data.SBV> (3 :: SWord 2) + 1
0 :: SWord 2
Prelude Data.SBV> (3 :: SInt 7) * 91
17 :: SInt 7
```

These also have the property that they can be symbolic:

```hs
Prelude Data.SBV> sat $ \(x :: SWord 4) y -> x + y .== 3
Satisfiable. Model:
  s0 = 14 :: WordN 4
  s1 =  5 :: WordN 4
```

So long as you stick to constant values, everything should be constant-folded, of course.